# GSON - How to easily parse this Json?

Tags: android, json, gson

**Hello everyone!**
Here is my json:

```
{"USER_DATA":{"USER_NAME":"John","PERMISSIONS" : "Admin"}}
```

When I try this code:

```
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Entity>>() {}.getType();
 List<Entity> entities = gson.fromJson(myJson, listType);
```

I get an error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY, but was BEGIN_OBJECT.

Any simple solutions to this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `s` is your String:

```
JSONObject mJson = new JSONObject(s);

JSONObject mInnerJson = mJson.getJSONObject("USER_DATA");

String mUserName = mInnerJson.getString("USER_NAME");
String mPermission = mInnerJson.getString("PERMISSIONS");
```

then you can use the Strings as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using GSON and Custom classes that is filled by GSON.

Define **UserData.java** class:

```
public class UserData {
    @SerializedName("USER_NAME")
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("PERMISSIONS")
    private String permissions;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }
}
```

Define its container **UserDataHolder.java** class

```
public class UserDataHolder {
    @SerializedName("USER_DATA")
    private UserData userData;

    public UserData getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }
}
```

Try below code:

```
String jsonString = "{\"USER_DATA\":{\"USER_NAME\":\"John\",\"PERMISSIONS\" : \"Admin\"}}";

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();

UserDataHolder userDataHolder = gson.fromJson(jsonString, UserDataHolder.class);
UserData userData = userDataHolder.getUserData();
// get user name and use it
userData.getUserName();

// get user permissions and use it
userData.getPermissions();
```

**Note:** I like to write code with camel case standarts so I used `SerializedName` annotation. Do not forget to import `com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName` at your custom classes if you want to use `SerializedName` annotation.